# Printing different messages by command exit code

Tags: bash, exit-code

So I have this in my .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building Space Cubes X for Mac...."
make OS=APPLE -k

if [$? -eq 0]
then
    echo "Build completed."
    echo "You can find the build under (THIS_FOLDER)/bin/build."
else
    echo "Build failed! Check above for error messages!"
fi
```

The problem is, bash prints this message I don't even understand:

```
./build-mac.sh: line 7: [0: command not found
```

Any help or advice is appreciated!

I'm running on a Mac with Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add additional spaces on the `if` line around the square brackets.  Change your code to:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

The reason this is required is that `[` is a command itself (a synonym on *nix for `test`) and you need to execute the `[` command not the (non-existing) `[$?` command.

Answer (score 2):

Might as well not use `$?` at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building Space Cubes X for Mac...."

if make OS=APPLE -k ; then
    echo "Build completed."
    echo "You can find the build under (THIS_FOLDER)/bin/build."
else
    echo "Build failed! Check above for error messages!"
fi
```